# converter array to key and value in array php

Tags: php, arrays

i have array look like this:

```
$arr=array(
   'key1'=>'value1',
   'key2'=>'value2',
   0=>array(
      'sub1_key1'=>'sub1_value1',
      'sub1_key2'=>'sub1_value2',
   ),
   'key3'=>array(
      'sub2_key1'=>'sub2_value1',
      'sub2_key2'=>'sub2_value2',
   ),
   //....
);
```

how to converter array $arr to array look like this:

```
$arr=array(
   'key1'=>'value1',
   'key2'=>'value2',
   'sub1_key1'=>'sub1_value1',
   'sub1_key2'=>'sub1_value2',
   'sub2_key1'=>'sub2_value1',
   'sub2_key2'=>'sub2_value2',
   //....
);
```

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
$new = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) { // having nested loop to save keys and values into new array
            $new[$k] = $v;
        }
    } else {
        $new[$key] = $value; // leaving values intact
    }
}

print_r($new); // returns  Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 [sub1_key1] => sub1_value1 [sub1_key2] => sub1_value2 [sub2_key1] => sub2_value1 [sub2_key2] => sub2_value2 )
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5mz-10j)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Try this out. This works for you hopefully.

This is not trivial, because you are going to reduce multi.dim. array to single one and also ignore the key of the first array.
I have tested the following code and it produces that result you have shown.

```
function ChangeArrayToSingleArray($array) {  
   if (!$array) return false; 
   $flat = array(); 
   $iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)); 

   foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value)
     $flat[$key] = $value; 
     return $flat; 
} 

var_dump(ChangeArrayToSingleArray($arr));
```

output is some thing like.

```
array (size=6)
  'key1' => string 'value1' (length=6)
  'key2' => string 'value2' (length=6)
  'sub1_key1' => string 'sub1_value1' (length=11)
  'sub1_key2' => string 'sub1_value2' (length=11)
  'sub2_key1' => string 'sub2_value1' (length=11)
  'sub2_key2' => string 'sub2_value2' (length=11)
```

Comment: Good answer too, but I think the previous one is more easier to be understood. At least for me.

Comment: It uses  Construct a RecursiveIteratorIterator http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php and RecursiveArrayIterator http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

Use array_walk () function that may help you https://www.php.net/array_walk

Comment: How to implement array_walk with this? Please, show us, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
function flatten($array) {
   $new_array = array();
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if ( is_array($value) ) {
         $new_array = array_merge ( $new_array, flatten($value));
      } else {
         $new_array[$key] = $value;
      }
   }
   return $new_array;
}
```

then you can just call :

```
$flattened_array = flatten($arr);
```

in your case

this will work with any depth array as it works recursively

here's the [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pct-8jq) demo

Comment: It is not saving `key1` and `key2` though !

Comment: According to your update your function only returns first to indices, aren't you testing your code ! ?